# Guitar anaphora resolution tool

Tags: nlp

I found a tool for anophora resolution named as guitar.

http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/Research/nle/GuiTAR/

I can find that the tool solves anaphora for the example they have given, but ehrn i try to execute the script, it asks for ltchunk script which is nowhere available on net.. can anyone please tell me how to use this tool or any other simple anaphoora resolution tool.. please..

code:

```
cat $1 |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\[\[" "@|" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\]\]" "|@" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\(\(" "@~" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\)\)" "~@" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\(" "~~~" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\)" "~~" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\[" "@@@" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\]" "@@" |
ltchunk -show_tags |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\[\[" "<ne>" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\]\]" "</ne>" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\(\(" "<ve>" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\)\)" "</ve>" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "@\|" " [_( [_( " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\|@" " ]_) ]_) " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "@~" " (_( (_( " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "~@" " )_) )_) " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "~~~" " (_( " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "~~" " )_) " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "@@@" " [_( " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "@@" " ]_) " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\._\." " ._. " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\?_\." " ?_. " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\!_\." " !_. " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\;_:" " ;_: " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "\:_:" " :_: " |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer \"_ " "\"_ |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "'_" " '_" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.StringReplacer "'s_" " 's_" |
java -cp gtar1.1.jar uk.ac.essex.malexa.nlp.dp.GuiTAR.txtToXML.XMLConverter $2

######## COMMENTS #########
### A script that opens a file provided as a parameter
### and replaces a given pattern of characters with a replacement string.
### The replacements go as follows:
### Pre-ltchunk processing:
### A sequence '[[', ']]', '((', or '))' in the original file
### is replaced by '@|', '|@', '@~', '~@'  respectively.
### Then ltchunk is run over the resulting file.
### Post-ltchunk processing:
### A sequence '[[', ']]', '((', or '))'
### is replaced by '<ne>', '</ne>', '<ve>', '</ve>' respectively.
### And finally return the original symbols hided during the pre-processing phase:
### A sequence '@|', '|@', '@~', '~@'
### is replaced by '[_([_(', ']_)]_)', '(_((_(', ')_))_)' respectively.
### The original symbols are returned in a format as if they were also processed by ltchunk.
### Notes:
### ne - stands for nominal expression
### ve - stands for verbal expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to do a bit of reverse engineering to figure out how to fit this into the pipeline you quoted, but `ltchunk` is very likely an earlier version of the chunker available as part of the [LT-TTT2](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/software/lt-ttt2) package.  You probably need to apply the entire TTT2 pipeline to use the chunker, so check out the documentation.

Comment: Thank u..I am doing all kind of reverse engineering here, the new chunk doesnot provide the actual input of the parser.. so if i could the older version it would be good

Comment: I can't find the older version anywhere, either.  If you can find it, it would be called LT-TTT.  Just from looking at the code you showed, it looks like the output format has changed from a bracket-based annotation to something XML-based.  I don't know any more details about the differences, sorry.  I saw your other question about the Stanford CoreNLP coreference annotator, which you probably have a better chance of getting working without too much hacking.